# Are there any plans to remake the Eragon movie?

Tags: movie, inheritance-cycle

Eragon is a wonderful book and I wouldn’t have survived middle school without it. It’s one of the easiest to read fantasy series (second only to the Hobbit, in my very limited opinion) but I was very disappointed by the 2006 film.

**Has there been talk about another movie?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You might want to read [ask]; this question is a bit conversational, and your final question isn't completely the same as the question in your title.  Are you asking if there are any plans to re-make the movie, or if there are plans for a sequel?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Like @DavidW said take a peek at that link, but also taking the [tour] will help you out in understanding how the site is different to what you might expect. Hope to see you around soon.

Comment: Eh, depends on what you call talk. Disney owns the rights (after the fox acquisition), and they've been reportedly considering it for D+, but these types of discussions typically happen behind closed doors and as of now there has not been anything offical said.

Answer (score 10):

As of November 2022, the books are in development to be adapted as a TV show. It remains to be seen whether this actually happens or not.

> **An “Eragon” live-action TV series is in early development at Disney+,
> Variety has learned exclusively.**
>
> The series would be based on the Christopher Paolini young adult novel
> series “The Inheritance Cycle,” with “Eragon” being the first of the
> four books in that series.
>
> Paolini will serve as co-writer and executive producer on the series.
> Bert Salke will executive produce under his Co-Lab 21 banner, with
> 20th Television producing. Salke is currently under an overall deal
> with Disney Television Studios, of which 20th TV is a part. The search
> is currently on for a showrunner.
>
> “This has been a long time coming,” Paolini said in a statement posted
> on Twitter. “I can’t tell you how many conversations, meetings, and
> messages were needed in order to reach this point. And we’re still
> just at the beginning! However, none of this would have been possible
> without everyone who has read the books, supported the tweetstorms,
> and participated in this fandom over the years. So a huge thank you
> from me to every Alagaësian out there. You brought the thunder.”
>
> <sub><sup>**[‘Eragon’ TV Series Adaptation in Development at Disney+ (EXCLUSIVE)](https://variety.com/2022/tv/news/eragon-tv-series-disney-plus-1235325019/)**</sup></sub>

and

> I’m attached to both co-write and produce! And yes, I’m extremely
> excited for what the future holds. At the moment, I can’t go into
> details—it’s still early days with regard to this project—but I can
> say that I’m very pleased with the team I’m working with at 20th
> Television, Disney Branded Television, and Disney+. These are smart,
> passionate people, and I’m looking forward to making the best possible
> Eragon/Inheritance Cycle adaptation with them.
>
> <sub><sup>[Christopher Paolini offers an update on the Eragon Disney+ TV show!](http://www.shurtugal.com/2022/07/28/christopher-paolini-offers-an-update-on-the-eragon-disney-tv-show/)</sup></sub>

<s>The author certainly [wants a remake](https://mobile.twitter.com/paolini/status/1406628040323502082?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1406628040323502082%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fpublish.twitter.com%2F%3Fquery%3Dhttps3A2F2Ftwitter.com2Fpaolini2Fstatus2F1406628040323502082widget%3DTweet), but there's no sign that Disney (the current rights-holders) have any intention of remaking Eragon, or any of the books in the series into a new movie or TV series.</s>

The author made this clear in an [instagram post in July 2021](https://www.instagram.com/p/CRXEq_SlIEK/?utm_source=ig_embed), and there haven't been any substantive updates since.

> Greetings, Alagaësians! Once again, I want to
> thank you for your incredible support and
> enthusiasm during the #EragonRemake
> tweetstorm. It definitely got @Disney’s
> attention. Alas, I’ve heard through official
> channels that—at the moment—Disney is holding
> off on making any more expensive series like
> Eragon until their business is back to pre-
> pandemic levels. Nevertheless, the tweetstorm
> really made them sit up and take notice. And if
> the hashtag ends up trending again at some
> point, I’m sure that wouldn’t hurt.. .. :-) Once
> again, my heartfelt thanks, and as always: Atra
> esterní ono thelduin.